# gridview select problem

Tags: asp.net

work on vs05 asp.net .....My gridview have 10 rows .After select a gridview row ,my browser scroll up on gridview header ......**i want scroll don't move**....how to set scroll fixed on selected row

Answer (score 0):

Is the browser submitting a form when you make the selection?

If so, you should look at ways to prevent the post-back.  You could turn autopostback off on the grid, then manage the multi-selection using AJAX.  If it's a Microsoft ASP.NET GridView, I bet there's functionality in the MS ASP.NET Ajax toolkit that'll do this for you.

Tom Brown says:

> There is a @Page directive MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback - set this to true

Though I'd be careful to test this in all browsers, and to be honest, you probably don't want a postback just because a grid row is selected.  You want the behaviour to be that you select the grid rows you want, **then** submit the form.  This will give your users a much more pleasant (and speedy) experience.  Otherwise, if they click too quickly, some of the rowselection postbacks will be missed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a @Page directive MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback - set this to true